Confidence Interval for Regression Values
From this article, I understand the idea behind the Confidence Interval for the Individual Response.
However I don't understand the part on Confidence Interval for Prediction of Mean Response, if we insert a specific value of X into the equation, should it not return the confidence interval of a specific value of Y? How can a specific value of X as an input return a confidence interval for the mean value of Y?
